# Form get data from collection

Tags: symfony

I have a FormType "Questionnaire" and a Subform "Question" as collection. The subform "Question" have a form value which is not mapped by the entity "Question".

How can i access the not mapped value from the subform / collection in the controller which receives the main form "Questionnaire" for saving this form.

I can get the not mapped fields from "Questionnaire" like:

```
$form->get('notMappedFieldName')->getData()
```

But i'm not sure how can i get this from collection, can someone help me to solve my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the Question sub-form / collection in your Questionnaire form is called 'questions':

```
$questionForms = $form->get('questions');

foreach ($questionForms as $questionForm)
{
   $notMappedQuestionData = $questionForm->get('notMappedFieldName')->getData();
}
```

Comment: but i have many questions in my collection. I would like to retrieve the "notMappedFieldName" for every question.